# Processing 2.0b8: Virtual Memory Size increasing on macosx

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, processing

I'm debugging my app, it should be running during several hours when deployed.
I've let the app running and I found it crashed after 4-5 hours with an Out of Memory Error.
I'm on a Mac, OSX 10.8.2.
What I'm seeing in the Activity Monitor is that the process has a stable Real Memory Size (around 350 Mb), but it's Virtual Memory Size it's slowly increasing. 
Is it normal? Can this be the origin of my problem?
Thanks as always for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to reply my own question to help anyone with the same issue....
After lot of debugging, after breaking apart my app in little chunks, looks like my memory leak it's created by PGraphics object ONLY if it's render mode is set to P3D.

I don't know why, the issue it's not solved but by finding the problem I could code a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Good bet that your application is accumulating data without ever releasing it. If you're using anything dynamically allocating like HashMaps or ArrayLists or the like, those are prime suspects. Depending on how big your code is, you may have to start reducing your codebase and monitoring memory usage over 10 minute spans to find out at what point memory no longer accumulates.